# How to configure kafka chart to expose both: kafka-metrics and kafka-jmx-metrics to prometheus?

Tags: apache-kafka, prometheus, bitnami, servicemonitor, kafka-exporter

We use kafka chart (version 17) as a dependency of our chart.
And for I try to configure monitoring of that kafka.

**values.yaml:**

```
kafka:
  metrics:
    kafka:
      enabled: true
    jmx:
      enabled: true
    serviceMonitor:
      enabled: true
      labels:
        my.custom.label/service-monitor: "1.0"
   ...
```

Then I deploy my application and go to prometheus targets and I see following:

[image]

I am concerned about the failed request.

What I see ?

There are 2 services to monitor:

- jmx-exporter
- kafka-exporter

and both of those services are requested by 2 paths:

- /
- /metrics

But `kafka-exporter` doesn't respond on `/`. Is there way to configure kafka chart to work without failures if there are 2 exporters are enabled ?

### P.S.

Services definition:

```
spec:
  endpoints:
    - path: /
      port: http-metrics
  namespaceSelector:
    matchNames:
      - my-ns
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/component: metrics
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: dev-my-app
      app.kubernetes.io/name: my-app-kafka
```

2. 

```
spec:
  endpoints:
    - path: /metrics
      port: http-metrics
  namespaceSelector:
    matchNames:
      - my-ns
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/component: metrics
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: dev-my-app
      app.kubernetes.io/name: my-app-kafka
```

Comment: Why is `kafka-exporter` underneath `kafka-jmx-metrics` target? I thought `kafka-exporter` had lag and other metrics, **not** JMX

Comment: @OneCricketeer sorry, didn't get you. Could you please rephrase ?

Comment: In Prometheus UI, it is grouping your targets under a label. The two targets at the bottom if your image are correct, and are `kafka-exporter`. Only one of the ones at the top is the jmx-exporter (see `container` label)

Comment: Still didn't get you.

`Target 1:`
 a)  kafka-exporter
 b)  jmx-exporter

`Target 2:`
 a)  jmx-exporter
 b)  kafka-exporter

Comment: `ServiceMonitor/...kafka-jmx-metrics`. Look at the table below. Look at `Labels` column. Look at blue `service` or `container` labels. Each of those underneath that serviceMonitor should only say `jmx-exporter` or `kafka-jmx-metrics`

Comment: Yes, agree with you. Because 2 service monitors has the same selector. I checked it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I finished with following solution:

I use jmx exporter from kafka chart:

**values.yaml**

```
kafka:
  metrics:
    kafka:
      enabled: false 
    jmx:
      enabled: true
    serviceMonitor:
      enabled:true
      labels:
       my.super.company/service-monitor: "1.0"

  enabled: true
```

and registered kafka exporter as separated dependency:

**chart.yaml:**

```
  - name: prometheus-kafka-exporter
    version: 1.6.0
    repository: https://prometheus-community.github.io/helm-charts
```

and configured it manually:

**values.yaml**

```
prometheus-kafka-exporter:
  kafkaServer:
    - my-kafka-server:9092
  prometheus:
    serviceMonitor:
      enabled: true
      namespace: ""
      additionalLabels:
        my.super.company/service-monitor: "1.0"
```

Comment: Where is `.kafkaServer` value list used?

Comment: it is used inside prometheus-kafka-exporter helm chart I suppose

Comment: it is defined at:
kafka.kafkaSource.brokers

Comment: Oh, my bad. I was thinking that was just the Prometheus operator itself, and completely read over `kafka-exporter`

Answer (score 1):

> kafka-exporter doesn't respond on /.

That's because `web.telemetry-path` defaults to `/metrics`

https://github.com/danielqsj/kafka_exporter/blob/master/kafka_exporter.go#L700

Your ServiceMonitors are mixed up

- the one that ends in `kafka-jmx-metrics` should have `container=jmx-exporter` labels
- one that ends with `kafka-metrics` should have `container=kafka-exporter`

Currently, you've shown there is one of each container in the opposite ServiceMonitors. I suspect this is because your label selectors are the exact same, but for different paths.

If you only have one Kafka broker, you should only have 2 targets. One JMX Exporter (for each broker) and one Kafka exporter.
So, two brokers would have 3 targets: 2 JMX Exporters and one Kafka exporter (since it is for the whole cluster).

Comment: I've read about this variable. Can I override it somehow to avoid error ?

Comment: There should be nothing to override for the exporter. The ServiceMonitor definition is what has the path.

Comment: As you can see I use service monitor from kafka chart. Should I write it on my own ?

Comment: Maybe. Or you should open a Github issue/Pull-Request against Bitnami repo

Comment: Why not just change `path: /` to have `/metrics`? I don't understand what is running that has metrics on just `/`

Comment: could you please provide details how to achieve it ?
I am novice in helm so I can miss smth obvious.

Comment: It's not really a Helm change. You should be able  to use `kubectl edit` directly on the ServiceMonitor resource, for example

Comment: But if you wanted to edit the Helm chart, its right here https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/master/bitnami/kafka/templates/servicemonitor-jmx-metrics.yaml#L34

Comment: I think kubectl edit is a bad option.

Comment: As long as you're not re-running `helm install`, then it is a fine option

Comment: Could you please provide more details?

Comment: The resources will never change until you run `helm install` again. In turn, `helm install` runs multiple `kubectl apply` commands. But you are only changing one resource, so you only need to run `kubectl apply` one time, which is what `kubectl edit` will do when you close the editor

Comment: We use gitlab piprline to install chart. From my point of view kubectl edit is a manual step

Comment: Alright, well, I cannot tell you how to manage your k8s resources. All I know is that something with your `path` or `matchLabels` are wrong. The [JMX Exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter) documentation also says the path is `/metrics`, so based on the link above to the Bitnami chart, the hard-coded path is simply incorrect and you need to edit the resource on your own...

Comment: I've implemented my own service monitors and error is disappeared but anyway I see duplicated requests because both service monitors has the same selectors. I've checked services for kafka-exporter and jmx-exporter. They have exactly the same labels so I have no Idea how to distinguish them.
looks like services are configured here https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/master/bitnami/kafka/templates/kafka-metrics-svc.yaml

How can I can have different lables for services ?

Comment: Looks like only annotations can be different. As suggested, raise an issue in that repo and/or submit a PR. Otherwise, fork the chart on your own and make your own changes to add new Values section for service-specific metric labels

Comment: is it possible to override values on my side somehow ?

Comment: Only if you manually edit those files you've linked to before running `helm install`. You cannot change the values alone since there's no template to load anything differently

Comment: I meant... I add k8s template to my project  and i expect it overrides kafka template somehow.  Not sure if it is possible

Comment: You'd still need to open those `svc` yaml files in some text editor

Comment: Maybe `kustomize` is another option you can look into

Comment: I would appreciate if you could provide a bit more details about each option.

Comment: Both have the same result. Kustomize is explicitly meant to patch resources with static values. Otherwise, you need to manually edit the Helm template

Comment: I am asking about implementation details

Comment: Eventually I fixed it in that way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73151165/2674303